# Xcode plugin template cocoapods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I want to create Xcode plugin, and I choose [Xcode Plugin Template](https://github.com/kattrali/Xcode-Plugin-Template) from Alcatraz, then i close project add Podfile open workspace and try to build i get ann error every time:

```
ld: library not found for -lDTXcodeUtils
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here is a full output:

> Ld /Users/jakubmazur/Library/Application\
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/CreateFilesPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/CreateFilesPlugin
>   normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/jakubmazur/Developer/CreateFilesPlugin
>       export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10
>       /Users/jakubmazur/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Users/jakubmazur/Desktop/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk
>   -L/Users/jakubmazur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CreateFilesPlugin-dmzpluimftctcqhbkndjiknqtjnz/Build/Products/Debug
>   -F/Users/jakubmazur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CreateFilesPlugin-dmzpluimftctcqhbkndjiknqtjnz/Build/Products/Debug
>   -filelist /Users/jakubmazur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CreateFilesPlugin-dmzpluimftctcqhbkndjiknqtjnz/Build/Intermediates/CreateFilesPlugin.build/Debug/CreateFilesPlugin.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CreateFilesPlugin.LinkFileList
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.10 -ObjC -lDTXcodeUtils -lXcodeEditor -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework AppKit -framework Foundation -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/jakubmazur/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CreateFilesPlugin-dmzpluimftctcqhbkndjiknqtjnz/Build/Intermediates/CreateFilesPlugin.build/Debug/CreateFilesPlugin.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CreateFilesPlugin_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/jakubmazur/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/CreateFilesPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/CreateFilesPlugin
>
> ld: library not found for -lDTXcodeUtils clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any idea what should i set to do this?

Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :osx

pod "DTXcodeUtils"
```

Comment: Could you post your pod spec ?

Comment: I add Podfile to a question

Comment: The pod install command was successful ? Did you try to deep clean in Xcode ?

Comment: Yes, pod install without an error. I also try Clean, but what do you mean deep clean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following steps. Its a work around.

1. Remove all the scheme and add by clicking auto create schemes.(The pods schemes will be checked once its recreated, need it checked for working it).
2. Then remove the scheme file from copy bundle resources(is it shows an error).
3. Deep clean and run

Its building without any error for me, Not sure whether it shows any run time errors/ exceptions